# Flutter "google_sign_in": java.lang.IllegalStateException: Concurrent operations detected: disconnect, signIn

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am trying to login to my app through Google using Flutter's [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) plugin. Was working fine earlier, but when I try to log in now I now it keeps telling me there are "concurrent operations" running:

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Concurrent operations detected: disconnect, signIn
```

It happens when I try to call my `signIn();` and `logout()` methods. Very confused as to why this is happening, could it be something to do with my AVD?

This is my "sign in with google" button on the Welcome page.

```
CustomButton(
                "Sign up with Google",
                Colors.white,
                () {
                    Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .googleLogin();
                }
            ),
```

`googleLogin()` method from provider dart file, (using the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) plugin).

```
Future googleLogin() async {
    final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if(googleUser == null) return;
    _user = googleUser;

    final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    try{
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    }on FirebaseAuthException catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

`logout()` method.

```
  Future logout() async {
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
```

Full log:

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Concurrent operations detected: disconnect, signIn
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.checkAndSetPendingOperation(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:305)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.checkAndSetPendingOperation(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:300)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.signIn(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:399)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin.onMethodCall(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:148)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:178)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$handleMessageFromDart$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:206)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$6<omitted>.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in(21152):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/flutter (21152): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Concurrent operations detected: disconnect, signIn, null, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Concurrent operations detected: disconnect, signIn
E/flutter (21152):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.checkAndSetPendingOperation(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:305)
E/flutter (21152):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.checkAndSetPendingOperation(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:300)
E/flutter (21152):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.signIn(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:399)
E/flutter (21152):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin.onMethodCall(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:148)
E/flutter (21152):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/flutter (21152):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:178)
E/flutter (21152):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$handleMessageFromDart$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:206)
E/flutter (21152):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$6ZD1MYkhaLxyPjtoFDxe45u43DI.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (21152):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
E/flutter (21152):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/flutter (21152):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/flutter (21152):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/flutter (21152):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (21152):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/flutter (21152):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/flutter (21152): )
E/flutter (21152): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (21152): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter (21152): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21152): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:367:43)
E/flutter (21152): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21152): #3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:244:30)
E/flutter (21152): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21152): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart)
E/flutter (21152): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21152):
```

Comment: a couple of years ago an issue was added on similar pb on flutter github and obviously closed without solving see yourself https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44538

Answer (score 2):

This happen if you tap more than once too fast on the login button before the login process is completed. Try disabling the button when the first tap is performed.